# Not able to connect modern site with Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Connecting to modern site from SharePoint designer is giving below error.

```
Error : 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below command in the Sharepoint online powershell tool

Set-SPOsite  -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0